# From acceleration to displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, integration

Hi I am a major in Computer science and this question should be really easy for all the physics geniuses here:

I have a set of data points from an accelerometer on a moving object that basically follows the form.

X acceleration including gravity

Y acceleration including gravity

Z acceleration including gravity

Rotation about x axis

Rotation about y axis

Rotation about z axis

I want to plot the object in 3-D space, and, after some searching, I was told to double integrate to get displacement.

Is that the best way? It doesn't have to be computationally efficient as long as it's easy to understand.

Comment: First you have to calibrate your accelerometers and the rotation sensors, otherwise offsets, gain errors and, much worse, the crosstalk between channels will lead to significant errors. Then you have to use the rotation data to figure out the rotation matrix between the real accelerometer axes and the coordinate system axes that you want the result in. Then you have to invert that matrix and apply it to the accelerometer data. Then you have to subtract the gravitational acceleration and NOW you can integrate twice. Easy, right? :-)

Comment: Does the object rotate as it moves? i.e. Does "x" always point in the same direction, or does "x" rotate with the orientation of the object?

Comment: @SamBader: Of course it does. That's the fun part. The only way to make sure that it doesn't is by putting it on a precision guiding rail. Then, of course, you don't need the accelerometer. A yard stick will do the job cheaper and better. :-)

Comment: Yea it rotates as it moves. Well, the accelerometer is from a mobile phone, so I'm not sure how to access the hardware to calibrate it. Also with regards to does x rotate with orientation to the object , well.. I'm not sure myself. It's a Samsung galaxy s5 if it helps.

Comment: To make things more fun, your accelerometer readings do not include acceleration due to gravity. Accelerometers measure everything acting on the except gravity. Properly speaking, they measure [proper acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration). To make things even more fun,what you are proposing to do is called "[dead reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning)". Errors accumulate. Your orientation and velocity contains integrated white noise. Your position contains doubly integrated white noise. You need fixes to compensate for that noise.

Comment: I am using the variable "accelerationincludinggravity.x" so I think it has gravity included. Is it easier to do if I take it without gravity?

Comment: Your cellphone doesn't sense that. Go to the top of a building and drop your cellphone. Your cellphone is going to accelerate downward at $9.81\,m/s^2$. Your cellphone accelerometer will read **zero** acceleration. If your cellphone survives the fall, place it flat on a tabletop. The forces acting on your cellphone are gravitation, directed downward, and the normal force from the table, directed upward. Your cellphone doesn't sense the gravitational force. It does sense the normal force, so it reports that the cellphone is accelerating upward at about $9.81\,m/s^2$.

Comment: Hmm Ok I placed it flat and I get a reading of negative 10 for the x axis. I think that is the gravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you could get the displacement from accelerometer measurements, if you also had an estimate of the orientation of the phone at all times.

You would need to use the phone orientation to convert each instantaneous acceleration measurement into the same coordinate frame, and then subtract off a constant component representing gravity, then double-integrate.

To be explicit, let's take some frame where gravity pulls along the $-\hat{z}$ direction, $\hat{x}$ is east, $\hat{y}$ is north.

The phone can be pointing any which way, so it also defines it's own time-dependent coordinate frame, eg. $\hat{x}'(t)$ points to the right of screen, $\hat{y}'(t)$ points to the top of screen, and $\hat{z}'(t)$ points out of the screen.  This is the frame in which you get your accelerometer data $\vec{a}'_m(t)$.

Let's say there's a perfect gyroscope in the phone so you know how to describe the orientation of the phone in space.  ie you can write $\hat{x}'(t), \hat{y}'(t), \hat{z}'(t)$ in terms of $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ and $t$.  Then you can compute a rotation matrix $R(t)$ that converts between frames.

$\vec{a}_m(t)=R(t)\vec{a}'_m(t)$

And then subtract off gravity:

$\vec{a}=\vec{a}_m-g\hat{z}$

Then, assuming the phone starts at rest at the origin:

$\vec{r}=\int dt\int dt \vec{a}$.

Voila!

**But**, this method is very error-prone.  For instance, if your orientation estimate is off by even a tiny bit, then the subtraction of gravity won't work well, and the algorithm will think your phone is accelerating even when still.  A one-degree error could easily lead to being off by kilometers on the order of minutes, particularly since any acceleration mistake get's double-integrated!

See [here](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity) for a good discussion!

Comment: Wow, that's detailed.. Thanks alot.. I shall try to use a kalman filter to denoise the data.

Comment: Sure thing!  I'm not familiar with the Kalman filter, but just read through the Wiki page, it sounds clever, and I'm curious about where you'd apply it.  The wiki example included an application merging GPS data with a velocity-based dead-reckoning.  Is that similar to what you're planning?

Comment: It's somewhat similar except I have no gps data so I will use the phones starting position and orientation as the constant data. I will probably apply it before I begin to do any maths on it

Comment: Hmm, that's a definite bias, no?  Eg if the user starts the phone at point A, moves it to point B, and leaves it at point B indefinitely, then the output of your algorithm will steadily creep back toward A, right?  Or perhaps that's fine in your application...?

Comment: aww damm.. in this case, i need to find a new algorithm to denoise then. gonna take awhile.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything to stabilize the long-term results of dead-reckoning, but you could perhaps design the application in such a way that you only need to know how the position changes over short timespans.  I don't know what the end goal is, but this method should allow you to, say,  trace out shapes with the phone.  Let us know how it goes though! :D.  (Or if there's anything else I can do to adequately answer your question).

Comment: well i actually only need to track and plot the object for timespans of 10-20 secs at a time. so i guess the DR should not have that much accumulated error. sure, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hope it's going well!  By the way, if you've found the above useful, feel free to "accept" the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: On phone, I clicked the green tick. I think that is accepting the answer? It's useful but I'm weak as hell in maths.. So it's gonna take awhile..

Comment: That works, thanks!  By the way, the [sensors overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) page includes tons of useful functions that might save you some math (eg getRotationMatrix()).

Comment: Wow I didn't know such functions existed. Thanks. This should speed things up slightly.